# How to horizontally line up two .rows with CSS / Bootstrap gridsystem?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to recreate this [website](http://www.ysl.com/us) using my own styles & Bootstrap.

I cannot figure out how to align these two elements horizontally.

I want a grid for the `nav bar` on the left to be size `3` and the rest of the page on the right to be `9`, and I have that, but when I go to add the video, it just stacks vertically and not horizontally.

```css
   ul {
 list-style: none;

    }

    .nav-left-bar {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 font-family: Arial;
    }

    #search-but {
 list-style: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 width: 18%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 margin: 5% 0 10% 0;
    }

    a:link, a:visited, a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
    }

    a:hover {

    }

    #search-but:hover {
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
     border-left: 1px solid #000;
     border-right: 1px solid #000;
     padding-right: 50%;
    }

    video {
     display: block;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
     }

    .vid-marg {
 

    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>YSL</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-
    BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
    awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="nav-left-bar">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-3">
     <img src="ysllogo.jpg">
     <ul>
      <li>winter 17 collection</li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
      <li>la maison</li>
      <li>saint laurent collections</li>
      <li>saint laurent store locator</li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
      <li>shop women</li>
      <li>shop men</li>
      <li>sunglasses collection</li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
      <li id="search-but"><a href="#">search</a></li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
      <li id="bag-items">bag</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="bottom-navi-bar">
      <ul>

       <li>log in / register</li>
       <li>newsletter</li>
       <li>customer care</li>
       <li>shipping to: us</li>
       <li>legal notices</li>
       <li>follow us</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col col-md-9">
     <video src="https://md.yoox.biz/618203721001/201707/263/618203721001_5506271544001_5506259873001.mp4" autoplay=""></video>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 

 <script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
 integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have them in two different row divs, so therefor they show up in two different rows. Try changing your HTML to something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Purrfect Match</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-left-bar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                    <img src="ysllogo.jpg">
                    <ul>
                        <li>winter 17 collection</li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <li>la maison</li>
                        <li>saint laurent collections</li>
                        <li>saint laurent store locator</li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <li>shop women</li>
                        <li>shop men</li>
                        <li>sunglasses collection</li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <li id="search-but"><a href="#">search</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <li id="bag-items">bag</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="bottom-navi-bar">
                        <ul>

                            <li>log in / register</li>
                            <li>newsletter</li>
                            <li>customer care</li>
                            <li>shipping to: us</li>
                            <li>legal notices</li>
                            <li>follow us</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-lg-9">
                    <video src="https://md.yoox.biz/618203721001/201707/263/618203721001_5506271544001_5506259873001.mp4" autoplay=""></video>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- SCRIPTS  -->

    <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: holy crap it really worked, wow thank you so much. Such an obvious answer and I didnt try it.. thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Bootstrap cols inside a row. For example if you want to divide in 3 columns you have to use:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Now, in your site you want to divide a row with 2 columns, 3 and 9, so you have to do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3"></div>
 <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

I recommend to you to avoid "col-lg" if is not for a very good reason, col-md just work really well in large screens and also in medium screens!

I give you the codepen with your question solved:

https://codepen.io/Kristain/pen/GEVYyb

Good luck with the site!